# How to pass the context down in a hierarchy of POJO's?

Tags: android

I have abstracted the functionality of my app into lots of different POJO's. Now some POJO down the line needs access to the `Context`, `SharedPreferences` or what not. How do they get that access?

More specifically, consider this example:

```
Activity {
    B b;
}

B {
    C c;
}

C {
    method() {
        SharedPreferences.readSomeValue();
    }
}
```

My Activity uses a POJO B, which in turn uses a POJO C, which needs to read a value from `SharedPreferences`. How would I give C access to `SharedPreferences`?

The obvious solution would be to pass it down from `Activity` through B to C. That however would require to clutter class B with `SharedPreferences` for the single purpose of passing it down to C. B itself doesn't need access to `SharedPreferences`. I find this approach extremely ugly.

Another solution I tinkered with was to have a `public static` variable somewhere to store the `SharedPreferences` and access them from anywhere. This solution is not only equally ugly, it might lead to `NullPointerException`s if C is accessed in a different hierarchy from a different Activity.

Is there another way?

Comment: normal people would have just used constructor to pass activity to POJO, but you already labeled it extremely ugly. I don't think there is better not ugly way

Comment: Can you read the value from the preferences in your activity instead and pass the value directly to C?

Comment: You can create the singleton class which will create the object of SharedPrefences and instantiate SingleTon in your Application class in onCreate() so that it will get initialized only once and never be null

Comment: @AndrewSun: That doesn't make it much better, because I still need to smuggle it through B. And when C needs access to more then just one preference that's even worse.

Comment: @ShripadJadhav: A Singleton is basically just a static variable. What if I instantiate it in one Activity and then access it from another? As I said, I had NullPointerExceptions because of that.

Comment: What about dependency injection? A can create both B and C, and pass C to the constructor of B. That way B doesn't need to know about the context (or how to create C, for that matter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Andrew Sun's comment gave me the right direction. I now have a class called `Initializer` that handles initialization:

```
public class Initializer {
    public static void init(Context context) {
        A.init(context.getResources());
        B.init(context);
        C.init(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context));
    }
}
```

It's called in the Activity's `onCreate()` method:

```
Initializer.init(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a singleton class that handles POJO classes ?
In this case you can mutable the same object which is in Map not in your Activity.

```
public class AppVariables{
    private static AppVariables instance = new AppVariables();
    private Map<String,Object> map;
    public static AppVariables getInstance(){
         return instance;
    }
    private AppVariables(){
       map = new HashMap<>();
    }
    public void add(String key, Object value){
         map.put(key,value);
    }
    public Object get(String key){
        return map.get(key);
    }

    //In your A class
    AppVariables.getInstance().add("AVariable",A);

    //In your C class
    Object obj = AppVariables.getInstance().get("AVariable");
    //Now you can receive your variable in Activity C or any other java class
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting to have my own redundant infrastructure for SharedPreferences? And maybe even implement a change listener to keep it in sync? I think I'd rather pass SharedPreferences through B.

Comment: And SharedPreferences was just one example. How would your solution help me if I need access to the Context instead of SharedPreferences?

Comment: Lets say you have a class that can is not serializable. How would you send it from Activity to activity or to a service maybe? For every class you should implement  a Parcelable interface to save it into sharedPreferences or convert it to Json and convert back it to class with Gson again. These actions require a lot of codes and you should take care of maintaintance of it.